# On Plugin Activation, How Do I Check for Proper Transport Mechanism?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-remote-get, curl, wp-remote-post

For a plugin that communicates with somewhere else, I hear we're supposed to use [wp_remote_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_post) and [wp_remote_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get) instead of [PHP's Curl library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Okay, but is there a fast and proper way on plugin execution to test for a blog's PHP/host OS to have the proper transport mechanism installed? I mean, I could attempt a test POST, but thought WP might have a better, faster mechanism that I can test for? Doing the following is unacceptable:

```
if (!function_exists('curl_exec')) {
    wp_die('The CURL API is not installed with PHP. You cannot use this plugin without that. Ask your web hosting provider to install it.');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't cause the plugin to die like that.  Just check for cURL each time you need to make a call or fall back on `wp_remote_(post|get)` (eg. write a wrapper function that takes care of the check and send the data/headers you want).

BUT, if you really really want to disable the plugin if cURL is not installed, you can use an [activation hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) to check for the `curl_exec` function and deactivate the plugin if not.

```
<?php
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpse51312_activation');
function wpse51312_activation()
{
    if(!function_exists('curl_exec'))
    {
        // Deactivate the plugin
        deactivate_plugins(__FILE__);

        // Show the error page, Maybe this shouldn't happen?
        wp_die(
            __('You must enable cURL support to use INSERT PLUGIN NAME'),
            __('Error')
        );
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I believe that the HTTP api tries to use cURL if it's available.

Comment: Yeah, I found in this case that die() rather than wp_die() is better if done on plugin activation. But anyway, wp_remote_post doesn't always use Curl. On some hosts, curl_exec() is disabled, yet file_get_contents() or fopen() with a remote host may be enabled.

Comment: However, the real question is that I just want a quick way to test for the chance of failure with wp_remote_post() because none of the transport mechanisms might not be enabled. Checking simply for Curl stuff just won't cut it.

Comment: The only way you're going to see if that happens is by making a request.  `wp_remote_post` will return a `WP_Error` object if it fails.